# PHP concatenate variable to string inside of ternary operator

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I'm having some trouble with getting this ternary statement to work error free.

```
$longtitle = 'long-title-' . browser();
<h5 class="{{ (strlen($title_part_i) > 29 ) ? "'text-uppercase case-study-title-01 mb-0' . $longtitle" : 'text-uppercase case-study-title-01 mb-0'}}"><?=$title_part_i?></h5>
```

I'm trying to concatenate the variable `$longtitle` to the class name of the true condition.
I'm sure I just missed something somewhere, but I can't tell what.

Comment: Your quoting is all messed up. `"'text-uppercase case-study-title-01 mb-0' . $longtitle"` Just remove the double quotes.

Comment: It would be better to post the solution as an answer rather than editing it into your question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying - I actually prefer the other answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify it as follows.

```
<h5 class="{{ (strlen($title_part_i) > 29 ) ? 'text-uppercase case-study-title-01 mb-0'.$longtitle : 'text-uppercase case-study-title-01 mb-0' }}">
    <?= $title_part_i; ?>
</h5>
```

Your concatenation is totally messed. Try not to use shorthands as it can create more confusion.

You can also try doing the same with simple if condition.

```
<h5 class="<?php if(strlen($title_part_i) > 29 ){ 
       echo 'text-uppercase case-study-title-01 mb-0 '.$longtitle;
    }
    else{
       echo 'text-uppercase case-study-title-01 mb-0'; 
    }
    ?>">
    <?= $title_part_i; ?>
</h5>
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Perfect. Only thing is it was missing a space after ```'text-uppercase case-study-title-01 mb-0 '.$longtitle;```